# Movistar and OPNSense

Tags: opnsense

I have a web server on my ip 192.168.1.100 under DMZ ... with a Movistar WAN

I can access from the local network, I can access from the domains assigned to it and everything without problems, I can also access from other external connections of other companies, for example Fibertel ... BUT I cannot access from outside from other Movistar connections.

Repeat: im able to acces from any internal or any external conections of others ISPs... but im not able to acces from external conections from Movistar.

it's so crazy... im ussing the same config with my old connection from other ISP and it work fine.

Comment: Did you configure your WAN interface manually? How is it set up?

Comment: hello! PPPoE user and password.. the others in default...  and i test with Block private networks.. Block bogon networks enabled and disabled.. and nothing